# Windows 10 USB flash drive not booting, but linux (ubuntu) does

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have an bootable USB with windows 10.
I tried to install it on my laptop lenovo G50-80: I've selected the boot menu (after turning on the laptop via a small button: [here](https://i0.wp.com/trickiknow.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Lenovo-G50-Bios-Setup-Novo-Button.jpg?resize=800%2C450)), but the usb name wasn't there, I tried an USB flash drive with Ubuntu 18.04 on it, it worked perfectly.

The usb with windows on it is kingston and the second one (with ubuntu) is transcend, if it matters.
I have windows 8.1 (64-bit) preinstalled on the laptop.
I used microsoft [toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/software-download/windows10).
I want to install windows on 64-bits.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: The BIOS mode is UEFI and HDD uses GPT partitions.

Edit2: Now I see that the USB have the MBR partition schema. Quoting from tomshardware answers:

> By default the Windows USB installer creation tool will not change the partitioning scheme or file system of the USB device itself.

How can I change the partition schema and get this done successfully?

Comment: Do you have Windows 8.1 installed in UEFI mode or Legacy mode?  In other words, on a HDD, using MBR or GPT partitions?  Please edit your question to include this vital information.  As for the reason Ubuntu works, it's more forgiving, Windows has specific requirements when installed on a GPT partition.

Comment: I'm not aware of these specifications now, I will research a bit and I will come back with an answer, thanks.

Comment: Done. UEFI and GPT.

Comment: Use Rufus: https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: Seems like a good idea. Though, is there any possible way to make it work through microsoft installation tool? Thanks

Comment: It ruined my past PC days:(

Answer (score 0):

I used different usb slot (the black one: USB 2.0) and it worked.
Also, I used rufus with GPT setting.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think for windows 10 the USB drive needs to be formated with Fat or FAT32.
I installed Windows 10 on a surface 4 with uefi and it had to be formatted with FAT

Comment: It is formated with FAT